# how do return a file line number in C, so that I can use a for loop to printf() a sequence of lines from the file?

Tags: c, numbers, return, line

I pasted my function below, and this is what I want it to do: If strcmp(line, info) == 0 (true), return "file.txt" line number, then printf() line -1 through line +6 from file to terminal. ie. if match is found on line 10, output should be

```
line 9
line 10
...
line 16
```

I'm sure there's something wrong with my for loop, as this function is written, it compiles and the program runs, but nothing is printed to the screen if (true).

```
int check_duplicates(string info)
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    int line-number
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        if (strcmp(line, info) == 0)
        {
            for (int i = (line_number -1); i < (line_number + 6); i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", line);
            }
            return 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could help me fix whatever I've done wrong, that would be awesome!

Comment: Save the previous line in another variable.

Comment: How would you expect a loop with the condition `i < (i + 7)` to ever end? 0 < 7, 1 < 8, 2 < 9, etc.

Comment: Why do you expect `(*line -1)` to be a line number?

Comment: `*line` is the first character of the line.

Comment: I've edited the code, hopefully it makes more sense now. I don't know how to get the line number, that's what I'm asking how to do so that my for loop works.....

Answer (score 0):

To get the line numbers, use a counter variable that you increment after reading each line.

To print the line before the match, copy the line into another string, and print that before printing the line and the following 6 lines.

Assuming `info` doesn't have a newline at the end, you need to remove the newline from `line` before comparing it.

The loop that prints the next 6 lines should just count from 0 to 5, it doesn't need to use anything from `line`. And it has to call `fgets()` in the loop to read the lines, otherwise you'll just keep printing the same line.

```
int check_duplicates(string info)
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    char prev_line[100];
    int line_num = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // remove trailing newline
        line_num++;
        if (strcmp(line, info) == 0)
        {
            printf("%d %s\n%d %s\n", line_num-1, prev_line, line_num, line);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
                    printf("%d %s", line_num + i, line);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(prev_line, line);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this still returns 1 if a copy is found, but does not print anything to terminal.

Comment: That's not possible. There's clearly at least one `printf()` executed in the `if` block that returns 1.

Comment: I see that. I also see the program run here, and all that is printed is “duplicate”, which is triggered by this function returning 1, it would be nice to understand that one…..

Comment: I just tested my code and it worked as expected. I don't know why you're not seeing the output.

Comment: However, I had some mistakes in my code, I fixed them when I was testing.

Comment: I'm not sure, I appreciate you trying to help though. I'm rather new at this, and learning independently. I substituted the changes you made, and I still have the same result; returns 1 to function call, triggering "duplicate" to print on terminal, but nothing else. Which doesn't make sense, because as you said, there is a printf function immediately after strcmp(line, info) == 0...

Comment: What happens if you just replace the function with `printf("blah\n"); return 1;`?

Comment: I have a feeling your file text has CRLF newlines. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: I did some tweaking and managed to make this work. Thanks for your help.